# Gtk inspector force open Menus, Popups for inspection

Tags: themes, gtk3, gtkinspector

I am trying to find the css classes for certain components like context menus, menus from top panel, etc.

I cant use GtkInspector because as soon as I select the Object Selector icon, those menus get closed.

How can I force it to remain open so that I can inspect the widgets and classes used to define them?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, after running `gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true`, you can navigate to a menu and press Ctrl+Shift+I to inspect that object. (I wish that would work with Firefox, too.)